# How do I solve this error with Illegal Configuration?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to connect an outlet from a view ,inside a cell ,inside a collection view , to my view controller file ,but I keep getting this error .

Illegal Configuration: The runningCard outlet from the HomeViewController to the UIView is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do something like this, hope this helps.

```
import UIKit

class CustomCollection: UICollectionViewCell {
@IBOutlet var myView: UIView!
/*
 Please note you have to create the outlet yourself and then
 drag it to a view that you add to your cell, you cant use your view from your cell.
 */
}
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet weak var collection: UICollectionView!
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5//Number of rows in cell
}
var viewFromCell = [UIView()]//This array of views gets assigned by the collectionview method bellow.
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collection.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollection
    cell.myView = viewFromCell[indexPath.row]// This line of code gets the views from each cell and assigns them to the array of views declared above.
    return cell
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
 }
}
```

[This is how you implement your storyboard with UICollectionView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnkEi.jpg)